# How to build Dlib model used for android development?

Tags: android, face-recognition, dlib

I want to develop an android APP about face recognition.I want to use the dlib model(dlib_face_recognition_resnet_model_v1.dat)to get the face feature vector.I never do something about android development.What I want to ask is how can I port the .dat model into android development(.so).

Answer (score 0):

I recently made an android app which uses dlib face recognition. It is accurate but slow. Have a look [dlib-face-recognition-android](https://github.com/gv22ga/dlib-face-recognition-android)